# Changing default Font Thickness

Tags: fonts

I am writing my thesis and happy with the default LaTex font for body text. Well, not completely happy, the font seems too thick for reading on screen to me. I need to make it lighter. Is there any way to reduce its thickness?

Comment: The more usual complaint is that Computer Modern seems too thin.  But too thick or too thin for what?  For reading on screen, or on paper?  And as printed on which kind of printer?

Comment: You may find a font more to your liking here:
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Comment: @Thérèse Edited.....

Comment: Trying a different PDF viewer or changing the preferences in your viewer may help.

Comment: The font appears thicker if I use the default Computer Modern fonts in the OT1 encoding, thinner when I use the T1 encoding (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`) or Latin Modern (`\usepackage{lmodern}`).